# Ошибка сборки проекта - ругается на ненайденные ресурсы

Tags: android, gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven {
                    url "https://maven.google.com"
                }
            }
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "redixbit.restaurant"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    }

    ----------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
    <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
</resources>

-----
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Замените compileSdkVersion , buildToolsVersion , targetSdkVersion на 25 версию

Comment: Спасибо большое , помогло ) Но появились другие ошибки)

Comment: Если есть ошибки - говорите какие и где или задайте отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка вызвана тем, что у вас версия библиотеки поддержки отличается от `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`

Чтобы сборка прошла - замените `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`
 на 25 версию